# Is there a reasonable fix for "warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have implemented a simple templated class for a stack using linked list as such:

```
template <typename T>
struct Element
{
    T data;
    Element<T> *next;
};

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
private:
    Element<T> *m_top;

public:
    Stack();   // create an empty stack
    void push(T value);
    T pop();
    T top();
    bool isEmpty();
};
```

In the implementation of the `top()` which returns the value stored in the element at the top of the stack without removing it, I am getting the following error:

`warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

I have enabled `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall` options with `g++`. Here's the `top()`:

```
template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::top()
{
    if (this->isEmpty()) // isEmpty() returns true if m_top == nullptr, false otherwise
    {
        std::cerr << "Stack empty!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        return m_top->data;
    }
}
```

Since there are only two possible values- either the stack is empty or not, therefore the `if-else` construct. But what do I put inside the `if` clause after the `std::cerr` statement to make the compiler happy and not get the warning? I cannot simply put a `return;` statement as the compiler expects a value to be returned. Also if the stack is empty, there is nothing to be returned.

Additional help:
Is it a good practice to leave the compiler complaining when you know the logic of the program is right?

Comment: `if (this->isEmpty())` you don't `return`. Seems fairly straightforward. If you don't know what to return since there is no element you *can* return you can throw an exception.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Reasonable fix : don't do this! When a function is declared as returning something, you _have to_ return something. Create an empty value and return it

Comment: As for your additional help thing, no. That is usually code smell. Warnings exist for a reason and if you use a common compiler, the warnings are somewhat peer-reviewed. If you try to find out how to avoid them, you will learn something. Also: Do not use cheap tricks to avoid warnings. For example, some people do a try-catch routine and do nothing in the catch. This will avoid warnings/errors but is not what try-catch is for. In your case, go with something like if(empty){return invalid_value;} return value; (without an else, your compiler might be not bright enough to check the branches)

Comment: return `null` is the only value your m_top->data could have if is not pointing to anything... I meen return a m_top pointer, pointing to null.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Maybe in a different language.

Comment: @juanchopanza if the idea is to check if there is anything in the stack, he could define that the stack is empty if it's top pointer is == [NULL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/) or 0.  What do you mean by may be in a different language? am I missing something?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL You cannot return null when the function is going to return a `T`.  You need to return a `T` or throw and exception if the function must return a `T`.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes that's right, is it possible to return a T element with its `m_top->data` set to 0 or NULL value?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL `T` is not an `Element`.  `T` is the type that the stack stores like an `int` or `double`, `Foo`.  You cannot have "null" values.  It only applies to pointers.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand, thank you.

Comment: As a side note: There is a reason why [`std::stack::pop()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/) returns `void` and not `T`: It is simply not possible to get `T pop()` correct in all cases.

Comment: "Is it a good practice to leave the compiler complaining when you know the logic of the program is right?": sadly your code is not currently correct, and will break in strange ways. Specifically, you're in the realms of undefined behaviour. In this situation, the compiler can do as it sees fit which can include (and I've seen it happen) simply pretending the entire method doesn't exist and just returning random (uninitialised) values. If you claim to return something, you MUST return it no matter what code path is taken, or throw an exception / loop infinitely / abort the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like yours, when it is logically incorrect to return anything, you should throw an exception to make the program stop:

```
if (this->isEmpty())  {
    std::cerr << "Stack empty!" << std::endl;
    throw std::logic_error( "calling top when stack is empty is illegal" );
} else {
    return m_top->data;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I understand. But is there a better alternative to throwing an exception? Because I think it is not a good practice to throw an exception in a "data access" member function of a class which simply implements a data structure. It is also potentially dangerous.

Comment: @LokeshMeher Calling `Top` on an empty stack is a programming error. You cannot do anything about it - the code calling your function must be fixed and recompiled to make the program work better. When this happens, the best course of action is to crash the program as soon as possible. The other alternative, letting the program use invalid data, is far worse.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you do not return anything in

```
if (this->isEmpty()) // isEmpty() returns true if m_top == nullptr, false otherwise
{
    std::cerr << "Stack empty!" << std::endl;
}
```

If you enter the if statement then you output the text, exit the if statement and then hit the end of the function.  You either need a `return` inside the if statement or a `return` at the end of the function.

If you need a control path to not return but you need the function to end then the only thing I can think of is to throw an exception.  That will exit the scope and send the exception up the call stack until it reaches an acceptable exception handler.

Comment: I can't do either as the logic of the program doesn't allow it.

Comment: @LokeshMeher Well you have to.  If the function is supposed to return a `T` then all paths out of the function have to return a `T`.  What you can do to get around that is throw an exception.

Comment: @LokeshMeher Describe the logic. Usually you can go with return invalid_element and outside you check if it is valid before you go on. Or you write top as bool top(T& return_value) and go with something like T value; while(top(value)){ do_something_with(value);} (or, of course, while(not stack.empty()){do_something_with(top(stack));} and the exception if accessed empty)

Comment: @Aziuth: If the caller could deal with "invalid_element", it could also `catch  std::logic_error`. And the latetr is the cleaner solution, as the compiler knows it's an exceptional case. But apparently the caller cannot be fixed, so neither option is available.

Comment: @MSalters Dunno, the caller has to have some condition not to use top. The program crashing with the exception doesn't sound like desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something in the case:

```
if (this->isEmpty()) // isEmpty() returns true if m_top == nullptr, false otherwise
{
    std::cerr << "Stack empty!" << std::endl;
}
```

You have two(ish) choices.

- `throw` an exception
- call `abort`, `terminate`, or some other method which will cause your program to exit. Most compilers know that these methods never return, so they will not produce these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must either return something or throw an exception in your `if` statement.
Also take note that the compiler gives this warning when it doesn't know if the non-void function will always return value.

```
int remainder (int n)
{
    switch(n%5)
    {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return 2;
        case 3: return 3;
        case 4: return 4;
    }
}
```

In this function compiler gives warning because it doesn't know that `n%5` is always 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4.

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

You can prevent that by replacing one of the cases with default.

```
int remainder (int n)
{
    switch(n%5)
    {
        case 0: return 0;
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: return 2;
        case 3: return 3;
        default: return 4;
    }
}
```

Now compiler doesn't give warnings.